# Do i need to set up security rules in Firebase, if i only use it for analytics and crashes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-analytics

#### Firstly:

I am using currently Firebase only for analytics (users count) and crashes for mobile app. No usage of Firebase Storage, Realtime Database or Firestore (none of those were configured or set up).

#### Question:

Do I still need to define some security rules in the Firebase?

Comment: you don't have to specify any rules for using above features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Firebase project, neither of the databases nor a storage bucket are auto-created. So at that point there is no risk of them being abused by malicious users.

If you create a database or storage bucket through the console, it will ask what security rules to apply. If you select the restrictive rules there (the ones that have `false` in them, the database or bucket will be inaccessible, so there's also no risk of abuse.

If you (accidentally) pick the more permissive rules though, users can access your database or bucket, even when your application does not. In that case, you'll want to set the most restrictive rules:

#### Realtime Database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

[source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules)

#### Firestore

```
// Deny read/write access to all users under any conditions
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

[source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#writing_rules)

#### Storage

```
// Access to files through Firebase Storage is completely disallowed.
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

[source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules)

Comment: Chances are if somebody has your app engine access. You can't really protect firebase...